# Editing a simulation file while it is queued

Tags: pbs, qsub

Say i submit a file (file1.pbs) to PBS, and it is queued. In this file, I refer to a second file that the computer will run (file2.namd). Then, while file1.pbs is queued, I make an important change in file2.namd. Once I save file2.namd, I check the job, and it is still queued (hasn't run yet).
My question is: Will the change be implemented, or did the computer already read file2.namd, even though the job is queued?'
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried testing it out?

Comment: Yep, after some testing, it became clear that PBS only calls the second file once the job starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this with PBS, and the change was implemented. In other words, PBS calls file2.namd only once the job begins, not while its submission script (file1.pbs) is in queue.